# Get a single record from a table where the record is in all the dates

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[Table columns and rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIFe0.png)

Need records which are exists in all the dates of same table.
Here it should be record of x, y and z.
kindly refer table structure in above link image

Comment: Please show the desired result.

Comment: Please explain more. **exists in all the dates of same table**? what are your inputs?

Comment: need only distinct name field.

Comment: Could there be scattered dates in the table? If yes then how do you define **exists in all the dates of same table**?

Comment: dates are in sequence but in each date no. of records are not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: **( UPDATE )**

```
select name, t.date_cnt
from yourtable
join (select count(distinct `date`) as date_cnt from yourtable) t
group by name
having count(distinct `date`) = date_cnt
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6944b2/6)

For last 6 days:

```
select name, t.date_cnt
from yourtable
join (
    select count(distinct `date`) as date_cnt 
    from yourtable
    where str_to_date(`date`, '%d-%m-%y') >= date_add(now(), interval -6 day)
) t
where str_to_date(`date`, '%d-%m-%y') >= date_add(now(), interval -6 day)
group by name
having count(distinct `date`) = date_cnt
```

[<kbd>Last 6 days demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6944b2/7)

Comment: unrecognized keyword cross

Comment: @ShahidAhmed Updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: for same table, i need same output but only last 6 days from current date.

Comment: Thanks for above answer. Please modify it with last 6 days output from current date.

Comment: @ShahidAhmed Updated my answer, please check it again.